# Query in Ms Access 2016

Tags: sql, sorting, ms-access, grouping

I am using ms access 2016.
I Have a query result like below :
[image]

I need the result like below :
[image]

This is my query :

```
SELECT IIf([Posisi]="Supervisor",[Nm_Karyawan]) AS Supervisor, IIf([Divisi]="Dept001" And [SubDivisi]="Operator",[Nm_Karyawan]) AS Printing, IIf([Divisi]="Dept001" And [SubDivisi]="Tinta",[Nm_Karyawan]) AS Tinta, IIf([Divisi]="Dept001" And [SubDivisi]="Cylinder",[Nm_Karyawan]) AS Cylinder, IIf([Divisi]="Dept003" And [SubDivisi]="Operator",[Nm_Karyawan]) AS Dry, IIf([Divisi]="Dept002" And [SubDivisi]="Operator",[Nm_Karyawan]) AS Extrusion, IIf([Divisi]="Dept004" And [SubDivisi]="Operator",[Nm_Karyawan]) AS Slitting, IIf([Divisi]="Dept005" And [SubDivisi]="Operator",[Nm_Karyawan]) AS Rewind
FROM T_User1
WHERE (((T_User1.Group)="001"))
GROUP BY IIf([Posisi]="Supervisor",[Nm_Karyawan]), IIf([Divisi]="Dept001" And [SubDivisi]="Operator",[Nm_Karyawan]), IIf([Divisi]="Dept001" And [SubDivisi]="Tinta",[Nm_Karyawan]), IIf([Divisi]="Dept001" And [SubDivisi]="Cylinder",[Nm_Karyawan]), IIf([Divisi]="Dept003" And [SubDivisi]="Operator",[Nm_Karyawan]), IIf([Divisi]="Dept002" And [SubDivisi]="Operator",[Nm_Karyawan]), IIf([Divisi]="Dept004" And [SubDivisi]="Operator",[Nm_Karyawan]), IIf([Divisi]="Dept005" And [SubDivisi]="Operator",[Nm_Karyawan]);
```

And this is my table :
[image]

Please help me to the result of query as I need.
Thank you.

Regards,
Fernando

Comment: Hi ! You can post your images directly on SatckOverflow so they get displayed in the page ;) just use the "picture" button when editing

Answer (score 0):

You could use (fake ) aggregation function

```
SELECT IIf([Posisi]="Supervisor",[Nm_Karyawan]) AS Supervisor
, min(IIf([Divisi]="Dept001" And [SubDivisi]="Operator",[Nm_Karyawan])) AS Printing
, min(IIf([Divisi]="Dept001" And [SubDivisi]="Tinta",[Nm_Karyawan])) AS Tinta
, min(IIf([Divisi]="Dept001" And [SubDivisi]="Cylinder",[Nm_Karyawan])) AS Cylinder
, min(IIf([Divisi]="Dept003" And [SubDivisi]="Operator",[Nm_Karyawan])) AS Dry
, min(IIf([Divisi]="Dept002" And [SubDivisi]="Operator",[Nm_Karyawan])) AS Extrusion
, min(IIf([Divisi]="Dept004" And [SubDivisi]="Operator",[Nm_Karyawan])) AS Slitting
, min(IIf([Divisi]="Dept005" And [SubDivisi]="Operator",[Nm_Karyawan])) AS Rewind
FROM T_User1
WHERE (((T_User1.Group)=[Forms]![F_Jadwal1]![GrpShift1]))
GROUP BY IIf([Posisi]="Supervisor",[Nm_Karyawan])
    
ORDER BY IIf([Posisi]="Supervisor",[Nm_Karyawan]);
```

for null value try with Nz()

```
SELECT IIf([Posisi]="Supervisor",[Nm_Karyawan]) AS Supervisor
    , max(IIf([Divisi]="Dept001" And [SubDivisi]="Operator",Nz([Nm_Karyawan],''))) AS Printing
    , max(IIf([Divisi]="Dept001" And [SubDivisi]="Tinta",Nz([Nm_Karyawan],''))) AS Tinta
    , max(IIf([Divisi]="Dept001" And [SubDivisi]="Cylinder",Nz([Nm_Karyawan],''))) AS Cylinder
    , max(IIf([Divisi]="Dept003" And [SubDivisi]="Operator",Nz([Nm_Karyawan],''))) AS Dry
    , max(IIf([Divisi]="Dept002" And [SubDivisi]="Operator",Nz([Nm_Karyawan],''))) AS Extrusion
    , max(IIf([Divisi]="Dept004" And [SubDivisi]="Operator",Nz([Nm_Karyawan],''))) AS Slitting
    , max(IIf([Divisi]="Dept005" And [SubDivisi]="Operator",Nz([Nm_Karyawan],''))) AS Rewind
    FROM T_User1
    WHERE (((T_User1.Group)=[Forms]![F_Jadwal1]![GrpShift1]))
    GROUP BY IIf([Posisi]="Supervisor",[Nm_Karyawan])
        
    ORDER BY IIf([Posisi]="Supervisor",[Nm_Karyawan]);
```

Comment: it's work but not like I need. The resul only show the "max" only. The result only two line record not like the view I need. Any more idea?